# .gitignore does not ignore files

Tags: git, docker-compose, gitignore

I have a folder with source code. It contains the following files and folders:

```
/.git
/.vs
/bin
/obj
/src
/tests
.gitignore
docker-compose.dcproj
docker-compose.yml
```

File `.gitignore` includes the follwing lines:

```
/.vs
/bin
/obj
```

I excpect no file from `.vs`, `bin` and `obj` folders will be included in my repository. But every time I change my repository I see two files from folder `obj`. They are `\obj\Docker\CachedComposeConfigFilePaths.cache` and `\obj\Docker\MergedDockerCompose.cache`. Why git does not ignore them and how do I fix it?

UPD output after `git status`

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   obj/Docker/CachedComposeConfigFilePaths.cache
        modified:   obj/Docker/MergedDockerCompose.cache
        modified:   // another files

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        //some files

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Comment: Are those files already tracked by git? What is the output of `git status`?

Comment: Note also that a leading `/` means "relative to repository root", which may not be what you need. Usually I'd write it `.vs/` or simply `.vs`.

Comment: Your edit makes it clear that those files are already tracked. `.gitignore` has no effect on already tracked files, it only affects *adding* **new** files and will do its best to prevent new files that match the patterns to be added. However, once a file is tracked, it is **always** tracked. You now need to remove those files from your git repository.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the following: (you don't need them all but it will work)
It can be written more efficiently but to make it simple you want to ignore the content of the folders

```
.git/**
**/.vs/**
**/bin/**
**/obj/**
```

You want to ignore the files in the folder

---

**Another option is that those files are already tracked by git.**

Once you add a file to git it **will not** be ignored even if you add it to the `.gitignore`

## How to remove files tracked by git

```sh
# Remove any file you have already committed and you wish to ignore
git rm -rf --cached .vs/*

# now add the ignored pattern to your .gitignore file
git add .

# commit and push the removal of the ignored files.
git commit -m "Removed idea files"

#Push the changes
git push
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this command

```
git rm -rf --cached .
git add .
git commit -m "Update .gitignore"
```

please try to fix it. hope to help u